# 2 player coin game probability

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose two players are playing this game:
each round they flip a coin. If it's Heads, P1 gets a point. If Tails, P2 gets a point. P1 needs X points to win, while P2 needs Y. What is the probability of P1 winning?

Comment: Is the coin fair?  It might be easier by imaging them flipping $X+Y-1$ times

Comment: @gunes I agree that this may be self-study but isn't the OP supposed to add the tag?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen since there is no definite evidence that this was self-study.

Comment: @congriUQ you can add the answer you deleted to the above question as your effort.

Comment: @JarleTufto together with the deleted answer that the OP provided (I don't know if you can see it), the question quality will get much better. This looks like a self-study question, and apologies to the OP if I'm mistaken. However, the harsher move I made was voting this question to close. OP can still freely edit his/her question and the tags, and I'd gladly vote this for reopening if he/she adds his/her deleted answer as an add-on to the question to demonstrate his/her efforts.

Comment: @gunes I did see the other answer but didn't notice it was by the OP.  I have undeleted my own answer.   In my opinion the difficulty doesn't suggest self-study (although the solution is trivial once you see it).  The OP might have deleted his/her answer given that it was incorrect.

Comment: I'd still encourage OP to add his/her answer to the question (not as a separate answer) even if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ and $y$ denote the number of heads and tails needed to win the game by Player 1 and 2 respectively.  Let $$Y\sim \operatorname{bin}(x+y-1,1/2)$$
denote the number of tails in next $x+y-1$ rounds.  Without loss of generality we can ignore the fact that some of these rounds may not need to be played.

Letting $X$ denote the number of heads in the same rounds, the event
$$
Y\ge y. \tag{1a}
$$
is the same event as
$$
x+y-1-X\ge y
$$
which simplifies to
$$
X < x \tag{1b}
$$

The complement of (1a) and (1b) is that
$$
X \ge x \tag{2a}
$$
which is the same event as
$$
Y < y. \tag{2b}
$$

Thus, the game is decided with probability 1 during the next $x+y-1$ rounds and player 1 ultimately wins the game with probability
$$
a_{x,y}=P(X\ge x)=P(Y<y)=\frac1{2^{x+y-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{y-1}{x+y-1 \choose k}.  
$$
This can also be proved by induction using the fact that $a_{x,y}$ must satisfy the recurrence relation
$$
a_{x,y}=\frac12(a_{x-1,y}+a_{x,y-1})
$$
and using $a_{0,y}=1$ and $a_{x,0}=0$ as base cases.